# didSelectRowAt correct implementation

Tags: ios, swift

Can someone help me with didSelectRowAt, what is the correct way to show the selected cell's details?

I have a tableView that shows only people's names, one name in each row, so when I click on a certain name I want to show details for that person with said name.

Currently I am getting all the details for all the people in all the cells no matter which cell I select. Not sure how to actually display the correct details for only the chosen cell.

This is the only thing I have in the function right now:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    viewModel.navigateToNext()
  }
```

Not using segues btw, navigation is handled with that navigateToNext() function.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `indexPath` parameter indicates the location in the datasource array. Get the item and pass it to the detail view.

Comment: Show `navigateToNext`, but as Vadian says, I would think that you would need to pass the `indexPath` to that function so that it knows what to do,

Answer (score 0):

On your destination view controller, you would have a property to receive the `Person` (or whatever the name is) object.

So your implementation would be something like:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
    let selectedPerson = personList[indexPath.row]
    viewModel.navigateToNext(person: selectedPerson)
  }
```

(Assuming here that `personList` is an array and is the collection where you get your data from. Adjust accordingly, if it's different.)

On the `navigateToNext(:)` method, after you instantiate the view controller, you'll set its person property to the value passed in above. Your destination VC will have access to only that person's data.